# Is it possible to invoke cosmos db trigger from stream analytics?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-stream-analytics

I have some devices sending data to Azure iot hub. I am using stream analytics service to process the data and insert it in cosmos db documentdb. I thought about use cosmosdb trigger to update some docs when certain items are created, but I found that triggers are invoke via API or SDK. Is it possible to invoke cosmos db trigger from stream analytics? another way to resolve the problem?

Comment: are you saying the post-triggers are not execute when inserting data via ASA? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/how-to-write-stored-procedures-triggers-udfs#post-triggers

Comment: Right, post-triggers are not execute because CosmosDB triggers have to be call (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/stored-procedures-triggers-udfs#triggers), they are not automatic. From ASA it seems not to be a way to run a CosmosDb trigger.

Comment: got it. So yes, you could either use cosmosdb-triggered Azure Functions as already proposed. Or, and this depends a bit on the data volume that you are streaming into the db: Instead of sending the data directly into cosmos, send it from ASA into an Azure Function. From there you can write your insert logic (including triggers etc) yourself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no trigger in ASA for CosmosDb. But how about using [Azure Function Trigger for CosmosDB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-cosmos-db-triggered-function)?
This concept is using CosmosDb Change feed, and it is the easiest way to pick up the changes in your CosmosDb. Below is one example from the documentation attached in the link above.

```
#r "Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB.Core"

using System;
using Microsoft.Azure.Documents;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

public static void Run(IReadOnlyList<Document> documents, ILogger log)
{
  log.LogInformation("Documents modified " + documents.Count);
  log.LogInformation("First document Id " + documents[0].Id);
}
```

The alternative is to check on CosmosDB change feed manually and implement a solution that occasionaly takes the changes and does whatever you need.